# Merge feature branch to master in one step

Tags: git, git-merge

Is there short-hand version for:

```
    git checkout master
    git merge feature_branch_xyz
```

I imagine usage would be something like:

```
    git merge-to-target <target_branch> <source_branch>
```

I'm almost certain there is no out-of-the-box way for this. (I've checked [manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge))

But before creating custom alias (`git config --global alias.merge-to-target '!f765() { git checkout $1; git merge $2; } ; f765'`)
I would like to be sure I'm not reinventing stuff.

(just in case I misread the manual, or some other command handles such thing...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no native way to combine checkout and merge.

One alternative is to take advantage of having multiple worktree already checked out (see "[Multiple working directories with Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30185564/6309)"), and do a one-command:

```
git -C /path/to/second/worktree merge source_branch
```

`/path/to/second/worktree` would be the path of a worktree where `<target_branch>` is already checked out.
In that case, you would need only one command.

Note: to create such a second working tree, you go to your current clone and do (again with git 2.5+, preferable 2.8+) with the [`git worktree` command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree):

```
cd /path/to/local/repo
git worktree add ../target <target_branch>
```